# Concatenating files with windows copy /b: does not work for overwriting?

Tags: windows, copy, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate two binary files in `Windows`. The second of the two files is very large so I would like to avoid making a new file that is the concatenation of the two - instead, I would like the concatenation to appear in place, overwriting the larger file (hopefully this can also be faster?).

I tried the following:

```
copy /b mysmallfile.dat + mybigfile.dat mybigfile.dat
```

It asks if I want to overwrite `mybigfile.dat`, and when I say yes, `mybigfile.dat` now only contains the contents of `mysmallfile.dat`, rather than the concatenation of the two.

Very confusingly, if I try:

```
copy /b mybigfile.dat + mysmallfile.dat mybigfile.dat
```

It does not ask about overwriting, but does produce a file that is the concatenation of the two! However, the order is incorrect, I need the small file to be first in the concatenation.

I can't understand this behavior or how to get it to work. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: In order to concatenate in-place, the command would have to move all the existing data in the large file, starting at the end and working backwards.  There is no built-in command to do that, and it wouldn't be any faster than creating a new file anyway.  If you don't have enough disk space for two copies of the big file, you'll need to write some code, or see if you can find a third-party application that meets your requirements.

Comment: (By way of analogy, if you have a pile of boxes it is easy to put a new box on top, but if you want the new box to be at the bottom of the pile you have to move all of the existing boxes out of the way first.)

Comment: Thanks - when you say "you'll need to write some code" - maybe I can do that, how would you think to do this? The big file doesn't fit in RAM either.

Comment: That's why you start at the end, so that you're not overwriting data you still need.  Move a suitably-sized chunk at a time, large enough to be efficient but small enough to fit comfortably in RAM.  A few hundred megabytes is usually about right.